# Data not coming up on database

Tags: php, mysql

I followed this tutorial on youtube, for making a social network. I had to register my user. But when I register, nothing shows up on the database.. My files are:

index.php

```
 <?php include ("./inc/header.inc.php");?>
    <?php
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $reg = @$_POST['reg'];
    //declaring variables
    $fn = "";//First name
    $ln ="";//Last name
    $un = "";//Username
    $em = "";//Email
    $em2 = "";//Email 2
    $pswd = "";//Password
    $pswd2 = "";//Password 2
    $d = "";//Sign Up Date
$u_check = ""; // Check if username exists
//registration form
$fn = strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);
$ln = strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']);
$un = strip_tags(@$_POST['username']);
$em = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
$em2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['email2']);
$pswd = strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);
$pswd2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['password2']);
$d = date("Y-m-d"); // Year - Month - Day

if ($reg) {
if ($em==$em2) {
// Check if user already exists
$u_check = mysqli_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'");
// Count the amount of rows where username = $un
$check = mysqli_num_rows($u_check);
//Check whether Email already exists in the database
$e_check = mysqli_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$em'");
//Count the number of rows returned
$email_check = mysqli_num_rows($e_check);
if ($check == 0) {
  if ($email_check == 0) {
//check all of the fields have been filed in
if ($fn&&$ln&&$un&&$em&&$em2&&$pswd&&$pswd2) {
// check that passwords match
if ($pswd==$pswd2) {
// check the maximum length of username/first name/last name does not exceed 25 characters
if (strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25) {
echo "The maximum limit for username/first name/last name is 25 characters!";
}
else
{
// check the maximum length of password does not exceed 25 characters and is not less than 5 characters
if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5) {
echo "Your password must be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
}
else
{
//encrypt password and password 2 using md5 before sending to database
$pswd = md5($pswd);
$pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
$query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0','Write something about yourself.','','','no')");
die("<h2>Welcome to findFriends</h2>Login to your account to get started ...");
}
}
}
else {
echo "Your passwords don't match!";
}
}
else
{
echo "Please fill in all of the fields";
}
}
else
{
 echo "Sorry, but it looks like someone has already used that email!";
}
}
else
{
echo "Username already taken ...";
}
}
else {
echo "Your E-mails don't match!";
}
}
?>
<?
//Login Script
if (isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])) {
    $user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["user_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $md5password_login = md5($password_login);
    $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user_login' AND password='$md5password_login' AND closed='no' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
    //Check for their existance
    $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql); //Count the number of rows returned
    if ($userCount == 1) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
    }
         $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
         $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
         $_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
         exit("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">");
        } else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
<div style="float: left;">
            <h2>Already a Memeber? Login below ...</h2>
            <form action="index.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
                <input type="text" size="40" name="user_login" id="user_login" class="auto-clear" title="Username ..." /><p />
                <input type="text" size="40" name="password_login" id="password_login" value="Password ..." /><p />
                <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Login to your account">
            </form>
            </div>
           <div style="float: right; width: 240px;">
            <h2>Sign up Below ...</h2>
           <form action="#" method="post">
           <input type="text" size="40" name="fname"  class="auto-clear" title="First Name" value="<? echo $fn; ?>"><p />
           <input type="text" size="40" name="lname" class="auto-clear" title="Last Name" value="<? echo $ln; ?>"><p />
           <input type="text" size="40" name="username" class="auto-clear" title="Username" value="<? echo $un; ?>"><p />
           <input type="text" size="40" name="email" class="auto-clear" title="Email" value="<? echo    $em; ?>"><p />
           <input type="text" size="40" name="email2" class="auto-clear" title="Repeat Email" value="        <? echo $em2; ?>"><p />
           <input type="password" size="40" name="password" value="Password ..."><p />
           <input type="password" size="40" name="password2" value="Password ..."><p />
           <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up!">
           </form>
           </div>
```

connect.inc.php:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die("Unable to connect");
mysqli_select_db($con, "socialnetworkdatabase") or die("Could not open the db");

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

When I open the database on phpmyadmin, It shows : MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0000 seconds.)

I edited the code index.php and it looks like this:

```
<?php include ("./inc/header.inc.php");?>
<?php include("./inc/connect.inc.php");?>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost" ,"root" ,"iamanasian", "theworlddatabase" );
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
$reg = $_POST['reg'];
//declaring variables
$fn = "";//First name
$ln ="";//Last name
$un = "";//Username
$em = "";//Email
$em2 = "";//Email 2
$pswd = "";//Password
$pswd2 = "";//Password 2
$d = "";//Sign Up Date
$u_check = ""; // Check if username exists
//registration form
$fn = stripslashes($_POST['fname']);
$fn = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['fname']);
$ln = stripslashes($_POST['lname']);
$ln = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['lname']);
$un = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
$un = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
$em = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
$em = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
$em2 = stripslashes($_POST['email2']);
$em2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email2']);
$pswd = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
$pswd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
$pswd2 = stripslashes($_POST['password2']);
$pswd2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password2']);
$d = date("Y-m-d"); // Year - Month - Day
if ($reg) {
if ($em==$em2) {
// Check if user already exists
$u_check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'"); 
// Count the amount of rows where username = $un
$check = mysqli_num_rows($u_check);
//Check whether Email already exists in the database
$e_check = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$em'"); 
//Count the number of rows returned
$email_check = mysqli_num_rows($e_check);
if ($check == 0) {
  if ($email_check == 0) {
//check all of the fields have been filed in
if ($fn&&$ln&&$un&&$em&&$em2&&$pswd&&$pswd2) {
// check that passwords match
if ($pswd==$pswd2) {
// check the maximum length of username/first name/last name does not exceed 25 characters
if (strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25) {
echo "The maximum limit for username/first name/last name is 25 characters!";
}
else
{
// check the maximum length of password does not exceed 25 characters and is not less than 5 characters
if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5) {
echo "Your password must be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
}
else
{
//encrypt password and password 2 using md5 before sending to database
$pswd = md5($pswd);
$pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (id, username, first_name, last_name, email, password, sign_up_date, activated ) VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0','Write something about yourself.','','','no')");
die("<h2>Welcome to findFriends</h2>Login to your account to get started ..." ) or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
}
}
else {
echo "Your passwords don't match!";
}
}
else
{
echo "Please fill in all of the fields";
}
}
else
{
 echo "Sorry, but it looks like someone has already used that email!";
}
}
else
{
echo "Username already taken ...";
}
}
else {
echo "Your E-mails don't match!";
}
}
}  
?>
                <div style="width: 800px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto;">
                <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="60%" valign="top">
                                <h2>Enter the New World Today!</h2>
                            </td>
                            <td width="40%" valign="top">
                                <h2>Sign Up Below!</h2>
                                <form action="#" method="POST">
                                    <input type="text" name="fname" size="25" placeholder="First Name"><br/> <br/>  
                                    <input type="text" name="lname" size="25" placeholder="Last Name"><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="username" size="25" placeholder="Username"><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" size="25" placeholder="Email"><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="text" name="email2" size="25" placeholder="Re-enter Email"><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" size="25" placeholder="Password"><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="password" name="password2" size="25" placeholder="Re-enter Password"><br/><br/>
                                    <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Enter The World!">   
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>

<?php include ("./inc/footer.inc.php");?>
```

And it's still not working

Comment: You're not checking for errors whatsoever.

Comment: For one thing `$u_check = mysqli_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'");` you are not passing DB connection to it. I.e.: `$u_check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'");` - To check for errors, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`

Comment: Same thing for `$e_check = mysqli_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$em'");` - do `$e_check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$em'");` and for `$query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users...` - `$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users...`

Comment: You're also potentially missing `session_start();` since you are using sessions.

Comment: Have you tried to to validate you input by inspecting the results using print_r or var_dump? Also u don't have a database connection

Comment: I have connected to the database in the connect.inc.php Edward Manda

Comment: Don't paste variables into your queries. Use prepared statements and bind your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Firstly*, you are not passing the DB connection variable `$con` to any of your queries, *it's required*.

```
$u_check = mysqli_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'");

$e_check = mysqli_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$em'");

$query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0','Write something about yourself.','','','no')");

$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user_login' AND password='$md5password_login' AND closed='no' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
```

Use it like this and do the same for the others:

`mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ...`

`mysqli_query($con, "INSERT ...`

**Sidenote about your INSERT:** It is best to include the actual columns when doing an INSERT.

I.e.: `INSERT INTO table (column_x, column_y) VALUES ('value_x', 'value_y')`

You're also potentially missing `session_start();` since you are using [**sessions**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php), it is required and to be placed at the top of every file using [**sessions**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

You should be using `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` in order to get the errors, if any.

Also, adding this to the top of your files:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Remove the `@` symbols from your POST variables; they suppress potential errors.

---

Plus, instead of [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) which strips out HTML and PHP tags from a string, use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `stripslashes()`

I.e.:

```
$fn = stripslashes($_POST['fname']);
$fn = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['fname']);
```

and do the same for the others.

---

- Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

For password storage, use any of the following and do not use MD5, it is old and considered broken.

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
  For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

---

**Edit:**

Place the following and wrap the braces within the code you wish to execute:

```
// This is related to your named submit button
if(isset($_POST['reg'])){

// code to execute

}
```

which is why you're getting an `Undefined index: reg` notice.

---

**Edit #2:**

Place the following and wrap the braces within the code you wish to execute:

```
<?php include ("./inc/header.inc.php");?>
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

if(isset($_POST['reg'])){

$reg = $_POST['reg'];

//declaring variables
$fn = "";//First name
$ln ="";//Last name

// put the rest of your code

    }
}

} // closing brace for if(isset($_POST['reg']))
?>
<div style="float: left;">  

// rest of your code
```

---

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{

that is most likely caused by short tags not being set.

change

```
<?
//Login Script
```

to

```
<?php
//Login Script
```

Comment: Parse error repaired, but data is still not coming up on phpmyadmin, on the database

Comment: @AineshSootha Have you created all the columns and using the right types including the lengths being long enough to store the data? You're also not specifying the columns. Example `INSERT INTO table (column_x, column_y) VALUES ('value_x', 'value_y')` - use `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` as stated in my answer.

Comment: @AineshSootha `$query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0','Write something about yourself.','','','no')") or die(mysqli_error($con));` - Plus, you do have 12 columns in your table, correct?

Comment: and I have added the columns

Comment: @AineshSootha I'm not sure if it's relevant, but there are spaces in `value="        <? echo $em2; ?>"` remove them `value="<? echo $em2; ?>"` see if that makes a difference. From this point on, you will need to start using `var_dump();` for your variables, including `print_r($query);` to see what is being passed through your INSERT query. Also `value="<? echo $em2; ?>"` to `value="<?php echo $em2; ?>"` if short tags are not set/on and do the same for the others.